# Unable to load global scss when using vue-styleguidist

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-styleguidist

I'm using [vue-styleguidist](https://github.com/vue-styleguidist/vue-styleguidist) to generate a styleguide for my vue app, which is generated using vue-cli's webpack template.

I have a `_variables.scss` file and i want to load it globally when i start the styleguide server.

So following the [recommendation on the docs](https://github.com/vue-styleguidist/vue-styleguidist/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md#require) i added `require: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss/main.scss')]` to my styleguide.conf file, but it didn't help, when i use a variable in one of my components style tag, I get an error:

> Undefined variable: "$border-radius".

Here is my full styleguide.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./build/utils')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./build/vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}
module.exports = {
  assetsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
  require: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss/main.scss')],
  components: 'src/common/**/*.vue',
  webpackConfig: {
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.scss'],
      alias: {
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        '@': resolve('src')
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          loader: 'vue-loader',
          options: vueLoaderConfig
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          include: [
            resolve('src'),
            resolve('test'),
            resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find solution for your problem? i have same problem with global styles

Comment: Unfortunately no, I asked in their forum as well, and as far as I understand there is no way to do it right now.

Comment: But i used this code `require: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss/main.scss')]` and it worked for me. But I am connecting fonts globally in my file. And i have variables inside it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use

```
require: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss/main.scss')],
require: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss/_variables.scss')]
```

If you define the path to your variables file you can try to use in the docs server.